# Spark does persistence required for single action?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a workflow like below:

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile(input);
rdd2 = rdd1.filter(filterfunc1);
rdd3 = rdd1.filter(fiterfunc2);
rdd4 = rdd2.map(mapptrans1);
rdd5 = rdd3.map(maptrans2);
rdd6 = rdd4.union(rdd5);
rdd6.foreach(some transformation);
```

1.Do I need to persist rdd1 ?Or its not required since there is only one action at rdd6 which will create only one job and in a single job no need of persist ?

2.Also what if transformation on rdd2 is reduceByKey instead of map ? Will this again the same thing no need of persist since single job.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to persist if you plan to reuse the RDD in more than one action. In a single action, spark does a good job of deciding when to recalculate and when to reuse.

You can see the DAG in the UI to make sure the rdd1 is only read once from file.